# Check if key exists in tree with nested lists

Tags: python-3.x, tree, binary-search-tree, nested-lists

I'm trying to define 3 functions that will go into one function and then will return True or False, depending on if a specific number (key) is in the given list (tree). This is the code I've got:

```
def is_empty_tree(tree):
    return isinstance(tree, list) and not tree

def is_leaf(tree):
    return isinstance(tree, int)

def left_subtree(tree):
    return tree[0]

def right_subtree(tree):
    return tree[2]

def get_key(tree):
    return tree[1]

def is_innernode(tree):
    return isinstance(tree,list)

def func_traverse(binary_tree, func1, func2, func3):
    if is_empty_tree(binary_tree):
        return func3()
    if is_leaf(binary_tree):
        return func2(binary_tree)
    if is_innernode(binary_tree):
        return func3(get_key(binary_tree), \
         traverse(left_subtree(binary_tree), inner_node_fn, leaf_fn, \
         empty_tree_fn), traverse(right_subtree(binary_tree), \ 
         inner_node_fn, leaf_fn, empty_tree_fn))

def func3():
    return False

def func2(num):
    return num

def func3(binary_tree, left, right):
    if isinstance(binary_tree, int):
        return exists(binary_tree)
    else:
         ????

def contain__the_key(key, binary_tree):
    return key == func_traverse(binary_tree, search, exists, not_in_tree)

#Test example
contain_the_key(4, [6, 2, [[4, 3, 9], 0, []]])
>>> True
conatin_the_key(6, [[], 1, 5])
>>> False
```

What the problem is I don't really have any good ideas on how to write func1, func2, func3 so it will return true if it's in the list and false otherwise. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you also share what data you wish to include in these trees and what is the expected output?

Comment: Yes, its under "Test example" close to the end. @ParvBanks